# Do something when a single upgrade script has failed in DbUp

Tags: c#, dbup

Given we have DbUp set to look at our local filesystem set up as follows

```
DeployChanges.To
    .SqlDatabase(ConnectionString)
    .WithTransactionPerScript()
    .WithScriptsFromFileSystem(ScriptsPath)
    .LogToConsole()
    .Build()
    .PerformUpgrade();
```

Is there a handler or mechanism to handle errors in single upgrade script files? My current scenario is someone has written a bad script file (which is later fixed in a subsequent script) and needs to be ignored if there's an error.

I can't find anywhere in the docs where I can add some kind of logic to (not just) continue on error but to try and add some smarts around whether the script can be skipped because it was poorly written (eg create table without checking if it already exists).

Answer (score 1):

In the DbUp model, the logic necessary to adjust to problems in the execution of the script should reside within the script itself, rather than in the execution code.

For example, if you're worried that an add column script may fail because the column is already present, you should wrap the command in an if statement. Ditto a drop column statement, or other schema modification stuff.

If you're looking for a generic rollback handler, there isn't one. You can look at executing the series of scripts in a transaction, but that has its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the circumstances, but you could write a "run-once" script that takes place before the scripts from files. It would look something like this:

```
DeployChanges.To
    .SqlDatabase(ConnectionString)
    .WithTransactionPerScript()
    .WithScripts(scriptsHere) // there are a number of ways to provide custom code scripts
    .WithScriptsFromFileSystem(ScriptsPath)
    .LogToConsole()
    .Build()
    .PerformUpgrade();
```

I like to implement a class that extends `IScriptProvider` in the `DbUp.Engine` namespace. Which is fairly straightforward.

Now, with this approach, you can ensure that this runs before your other scripts, *and* you have the ability to either `RunOnce` or `RunAlways` via the constructor of a `SqlScript` object.